# Фавикон для модальных окон

Tags: python, tkinter

помогите пожалуйста разобраться с добавлением стандартной иконки к модальным окнам типа tkinter.messagebox.showerror и т.п. для windows

для обычного окна понятно как добавляется иконка. нужно просто прописать вызов примерно таким образом

```
root.iconbitmap('error')
```

или вместо 'error' прописать путь к графическому файлу.

но непонятно как добавлять иконки к окнам из модуля tkinter.messagebox
если не трудно, код покажите

Answer (score 1):

Изменить иконку диалога из `tkinter.messagebox` не получится, так как создание окна управляется внутренней командой `tk_messageBox`, которая предоствляет возможность задать одну из указанных ниже иконок (см. файл *PythonDir\Lib\tkinter\messagebox.py*):

```
# icons
ERROR = "error"
INFO = "info"
QUESTION = "question"
WARNING = "warning"

# message dialog class
class Message(Dialog):
    "A message box"
    command  = "tk_messageBox"
```

При этом внутри tk-интерпретатор проверяет иконку на соответствие именно этим значениям.

Можно предложить создавать собственные модальные окна с любым содержимым:

```
def msgBox(title=None, message=None, iconfile=None):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title(title)

    if iconfile is not None:
        top.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', top._w, PhotoImage(file=iconfile))

    # Добавить сообщение
    msg = Message(top, text=message)
    msg.pack()

    # Добавить кнопку
    button = Button(top, text="Ok", command=top.destroy)
    button.pack()

    # Сделать модально
    top.grab_set()

msgBox("О программе", "Это модальное окно", "update.gif")
```

Тестировалось на Python 3.6.1, Windows 7 64-bit.